# How to pass data to collection view controller embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I want to pass integer value from `MainViewController` to `CollectionViewController` embedded in `UINavigationViewController`. The code is written in `MainViewController.m` file within `prepareForSegue` method. I am getting warning as:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing '`CollectionViewController` *' with an expression of type '`UIViewController` * _Nullable'

The warning is for the code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];

CollectionViewController *collectionVC = [navController topViewController];
```

For passing integer I am using:

```
[collectionVC setReceivedCategoryId:categoryIdToSend];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[navController topViewController];` returns a `UIViewController` object. But we know that it is a `CollectionViewController`. So we add a typecast, like so :

```
CollectionViewController *collectionVC =(CollectionViewController*) [navController topViewController];
```

Answer (score 2):

`UINavigationController`'s `topViewController`method returns an `UIViewController`object as shown is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController).
Cast the object and it will work.

```
 UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];

// Add the explicit cast
CollectionViewController *collectionVC = (CollectionViewController*)[navController topViewController];
```